# run a command prompt command to start a solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

If command prompt command to run my application is "myApp.exe mycmd:something", where do I add "mycmd:something" to run my solution the same way in visual studio 2010?

Comment: you need to look up how to launch a console application passing command line Params.. there are literally `1000s` of examples online on how to pass command line Arguments 
here is a really good site you can use for some useful examples [1000s of C# examples](http://www.google.com) also Question...; What have you tried..???

Comment: What did you try? Did you search for `pass command-line parameter in visual studio`?

Comment: totally misunderstood the question

Comment: If my answer below is correct please update title of the question to something like "how to pass command line arguments in VS.." - you don't really need to "run command prompt" to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on solution (in solution explorer view) -> properties -> Debug -> Command line arguments.